# Object properties not showing in node-debug chrome / chromium

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, chromium, node-debugger

When running node-debug and rollover an object in chrome/chromium, I can see the objects properties down to the first level.  However if I try to expand one of the these properties by clicking on the drop-down arrow nothing happens.  The object properties I'm trying to expand on are not large, sometimes just an array of a couple of numbers?

Answer (score 0):

Updated node-inspector ( which I had done previously? ), now it's working fine...